# Classes are equal but not equal? Anomaly encountered when comparing classes in Python

Tags: python

I have an instance of a custom class and I want to verify its type as follows.

```
type(instance) == my_module.CustomClass
```

This returns False. Same when using `instance.__class__` or comparing via `isinstance()`.

However, when I pull up the debugger, I find that `instance` is of type `my_module.CustomClass` (as it should be, considering my inputs). It also explicitly confirms that it is imported from `my_module`.

I could exclude typos, since the following does return True.

```
instance.__class__.__name__ == my_module.CustomClass.__name__
```

The way I import the class should not matter, right?

Also, the instance was created within the session, not loaded from pickle or anything.

I'm sorry for not being able to provide an MRE, but I have absolutely no clue what to include.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: If there is no MRE, then there's no way to tell.

Comment: What about `is`?

Comment: Can you construct trivial classes that reproduce this error?

Comment: Your MRE should include a class definition, an instance of that class, and a condition check like the code you posted above that generates the same result (i.e. minimal example). Anyone should be able to copy and paste your code into a Python file (or REPL) and run it to produce the same result (i.e. reproducible).

Comment: In general, it's better to use `isinstance()` rather than testing `type()` directly, because it will be true for instances of subclasses.

Comment: `is` is no better.

Comment: The thing is, if I would be able to show you what provokes this behavior, I would probably already have the solution. At this point, I am just hoping someone might already have encountered this and can help me from their experience.

Comment: @Barmar I know, but that's off-topic here.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out it does matter how I import things.

After comparing `__dict__`s and finding static variables at differing memory locations, I knew the class must have been imported twice.

I had multiple files, let's say `definition.py` (where `CustomClass` is defined), `instantiation.py` (where it is instatiated) and `verifying.py` (where the check is performed).

`instantiation.py` imported `definition.py` with a **relative** import, while `verifying.py` compared the result of that (the instance) to a `CustomClass` version from an **absolute** import of `definition.py`.

I find this very confusing, since it is the same module being imported. Considering only using absolute imports from now...

Comment: Relative and absolute imports give the same module. Did you modify the search path so that the module *source* is at two different absolute, logical paths?

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://replit.com/@InSyncWithFoo/SOa77518397).